# Restlet 2.1.1 internal HTTPS-Connector

Tags: java, ssl, https, restlet

I tried to update from restlet 2.0.15 to 2.1.1. I get no errors and I can start my application. Using default restlet connectors, but when I try to access my ssl secured content over https:/url:port/ I get always a time out and absoluty no logs. The HTTP-connector works fine.

I also tried using the simple framework, but restlet starts only the HTTP-connector on simple and the https still on internal?

Here is my current configuration:

```
this.componentHTTPS = new Component();
this.componentHTTP = new Component();

Server serverHTTPS = new Server(Protocol.HTTPS, this.sslPort);
Server serverHTTP = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, this.port);
    serverHTTPS.setContext(this.componentHTTPS.getContext().createChildContext());

Router routerHTTP = new Router(serverHTTP.getContext());
String redirectTarget = this.sslURI + ":" + this.sslPort;
Redirector redirector = new Redirector(serverHTTP.getContext(),
            redirectTarget, Redirector.MODE_CLIENT_PERMANENT);
Extractor extractor = new Extractor(serverHTTP.getContext(), redirector);

extractor.extractFromQuery("", "", false);
routerHTTP.attach("/", extractor);
componentHTTP.getServers().add(serverHTTP);
componentHTTPS.getServers().add(serverHTTPS);

Series<Parameter> parametersHTTPS = serverHTTPS.getContext().getParameters();

// increase maximumSeries<Parameter>ds (RESTlet default is 10)
parametersHTTPS.add("maxThreads", this.maxThreads);
parametersHTTPS.add("sslContextFactory","org.restlet.ext.ssl.PkixSslContextFactory");
parametersHTTPS.add("keystorePath", this.keystorePath);
parametersHTTPS.add("keystorePassword", this.keystorePassword);
parametersHTTPS.add("keystoreType", this.keystoreType);
parametersHTTPS.add("keyPassword", this.keyPassword);
parametersHTTPS.add("needClientAuthentication", "false");

componentHTTPS.getDefaultHost().attach("/", webApplication);

// Start the http redirect component
componentHTTP.getDefaultHost().attach("/",
            new RedirectApplication(redirectTarget));

this.componentHTTPS.start();
this.componentHTTP.start();
```

Has anybody else this problem or knows a solution? On the previous restlet 2.0.* versions our code just worked fine.

Regards

Comment: Could you list your classpath entries and their order?

Comment: see https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/702